# События C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста с таким вопросом. Ситуация такова: на винформе находится много текстбоксов. И реализовано событие по нажатию на клавишу Enter. Как в теле события определить, с какого из текстбоксов оно пришло (какой текстбокс находился в фокусе при нажатии на клавишу)??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В заголовке всех событий есть параметр object sender, через который и можно узнать, какой объект является инициатором события.

```
private void OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    var mytextBox = sender as TextBox;
}
```

Текущее активное текстовое поле, можно получить через свойства ActiveControl самой формы, хотя почти со 100% вероятностью можно сказать, что поле, на котором отработало событие KeyPress на данный момент и является активным.

Comment: Ну, куда же вы, тут не так много спецов. И спасибо, конечно!

Answer (score 0):

Вариант выше проще, но я дополню.

У выбранного textbox-a свойство focused станет true.

Comment: Вам это не кажется хаком?

Comment: @VladD, простите, я не совсем понял, что вы этим хотели сказать.

Comment: > я не совсем понял

Он хотел сказать, что предложенный вами способ ненадежен.

Comment: Проблема в том, что между нажатием клавиши и приходом события другие подписчики могут уже, например, увести фокус.

Comment: @VladD, вы правы, я об этом не подумал. Спасибо, приму к сведению.

Answer (score -1):

Или так:

```
private void OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  var textbox = (TextBox)sender;
}
```